# Creating an array of object with cumulative sum dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have array of objects like this and require to calculate running total(accumulate sum) dynamically for N keys.

```
  let a = [
  {"subject":  "Civil", "a": 100, "b":50, "c":100 },
  {"subject":  "aero",  "a": 200, "b":130,"c":100 },
  {"subject":  "tribe", "a": 100, "b":100,"c":600 },
  {"subject":  "solen", "a": 400, "b":150,"c":100},
  {"subject":  "space", "a": 100, "b":100,"c":900 }
];
```

Required Output as below :

```
[
{"subject": "Civil", "a": 100, "b": 50,  "c": 100},
{"subject": "aero",  "a": 300, "b": 180, "c": 200},
{"subject": "tribe", "a": 400, "b": 280, "c": 800},
{"subject": "solen", "a": 800, "b": 430, "c": 900},
{"subject": "space"," a": 900, "b": 530, "c": 1800}]
```

I tried below using MAP as below :

```
let b = a.map( x => ({...x,"a":a1+=x.a,"b":b1+=x.b,"c":c1+=x.c}) )
```

I want to achieve it dynamically without writing a, b, c.

Comment: what is expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to cumulatively sum every property other than `subject`, you can do so by mapping the array to new values, keeping an object reference for each running total as you go

```js
const a = [{"subject":"Civil","a":100,"b":50,"c":100},{"subject":"aero","a":200,"b":130,"c":100},{"subject":"tribe","a":100,"b":100,"c":600},{"subject":"solen","a":400,"b":150,"c":100},{"subject":"space","a":100,"b":100,"c":900}]

const cf = {} // store running totals in here
const b = a.map(({ subject, ...props }) => ({
  subject,
  ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(props).map(([ key, val ]) => [
    key,
    cf[key] = (cf[key] ?? 0) + val // value is the result of the assignment
  ]))
}))

console.log(b)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: can I add an Initial value as well?

Comment: @RajseGodia you can initialise `cf` to whatever you want if that's what you mean, eg `const cf = { a: 500, b: -2 }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `.map()`, `.slice()` and `.reduce()` array methods as follows:

```js
let a = [
  {"subject":  "Civil", "a": 100, "b":50, "c":100 },
  {"subject":  "aero",  "a": 200, "b":130,"c":100 },
  {"subject":  "tribe", "a": 100, "b":100,"c":600 },
  {"subject":  "solen", "a": 400, "b":150,"c":100},
  {"subject":  "space", "a": 100, "b":100,"c":900 }
];

let b = a.map((x,i) => ({
    subject:x.subject,
    a:a.slice(0,i+1).map(({a}) => a).reduce((x,y) => x + y),
    b:a.slice(0,i+1).map(({b}) => b).reduce((x,y) => x + y),
    c:a.slice(0,i+1).map(({c}) => c).reduce((x,y) => x + y)
}));

console.log( b );
```

Alternatively, this can be done without reference to any particular properties as follows:

```js
let a = [
  {"subject":  "Civil", "a": 100, "b":50, "c":100, "zz":0},
  {"subject":  "aero",  "a": 200, "b":130,"c":100, "zz":40},
  {"subject":  "tribe", "a": 100, "b":100,"c":600, "zz":0},
  {"subject":  "solen", "a": 400, "b":150,"c":100, "zz":60},
  {"subject":  "space", "a": 100, "b":100,"c":900, "zz":200}
];

let b = a.map((val, i) => ({
        ...val,
        //introduce a temp property 'index'
        index: i + 1 
    }))
    .map(({
        subject,
        index,
        ...rest
    }) => ({
        subject,
        ...Object.keys(rest).reduce((obj, cur) => ({
            ...obj,
            ...{
                //use temp propterty to compute running total for every
                //property but 'subject', 
                [cur]: a.slice(0, index).map(v => v[cur]).reduce((x, y) => x + y)
            }
        }), {})
    }));   

console.log( b );
```

Comment: i want to achieve it dynamically i.e. don't want to hard code a,b,c

Comment: No problem. The second option should take care of that.